# Save changes maded in a List filled by disposed DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

Sorry i am new in EntityFramework Word; supose i have a List of Persons; i call DbContext to fill it; like that:

```
public BindingList Load()
{
   Using(PeopleDbContext pdbc = new PeopleDbContext())
   { 
       _return  pdbc.People.Local.ToBindingList<Person>(); 
   }
}
```

The problem with PeopleDbContext; it will be disposed of the end of the call; but how can i save the maded changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the *using* statement.
Make pdbc a private field/property of your class.
This way,the context will not be disposed and you can call .SaveChanges() later

Comment: Is there other solution; i am care about Connection;

Comment: What about pdbc.People.Attach(listOfDisposedDbContext) !

Comment: solution source:http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx